# xelatex - /faPhoneAlt undefined (fontawesome5)

Tags: xetex, fontawesome

How do i use this symbol - https://fontawesome.com/icons/phone-alt?style=light (the /faPhone symbol is in wrong direction so i want this alt version)
I am on latest fontawesome5 package on miktex as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf):

> Just use the official icon names converted to CamelCase with the
>   prefix \fa. [...] For icons ending with -alt, append a * instead.

So to use the icon `phone-alt`, you use `\faPhone*`. Alternatively, you can also use `\faIcon{phone-alt}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faPhone* or \faIcon{phone-alt}
\end{document}
```

[image]